# Read a path without slash

Tags: java, file, jar, filepath

Need help in understanding about classpath and file path. We have a third party jar where they need to refer commons-logging property file . The have specified in below way to refer it.

```
String fileLocation="commons-logging.properties";
```

If i place the file inside jar it works fine, which is not permitted. IS there any way to make the jar refer the file outside the jar. I cant make any code change. I tried to search for solution, but couldnt get what i want.

Comment: It is not permiitted *why?*

Comment: its a third party jar generated by different team. We dont have access to change the code

Comment: So put it in your own JAR.

Comment: you mean the code ? or file ?

Comment: Your question is about the file. That's what I'm talking about too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the properties file on the classpath of your Java application. You already did this by adding it to the root of the jar file.

One possibility is to add a specific folder, e.g. config, to your classpath. The properties file should then be placed in that folder.

Another option is to put the properties file into its own jar file and add this to your applications classpath.

But in the end I prefer the first option to add the file in a folder which is available in the [classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Comment: i tried to add a file in classpath, but it was not picking!! :( only if i add the file inside the jar it works!

Comment: You cannot add a file to classpath. You need to add a folder to classpath and then put the file into that folder.

Comment: Got i! Let me try and let you know! Meanwhile I have requested the team to add teh files in the jar. No reply so far :(

Answer (score 0):

Everything depend on how this `jar` trying to read this file. If it tries to open it as a resource, via `ClassLoader`, then it should be inside your jar, but if like a external file, then no problem to put it outside and use absolute path into that file.

So just check this functionality and if you need to use file from outside - you have to change it and open this file via `Path` or `File` classes.

Comment: they have refered it as "common-logging.properties". If i refer a file like, how will this be searched? will it search using classloader or will use application resource ? I mean how it searches in default if we specify this way? where will the application first look for if the path is without slash?

Comment: Using ClassLoader (usually all resources use this approach) it search in application root. Also, using general conventions, you should have `resources` folder in your project structure. This folder should be mapped in you IDE as project resources and included to your build. After build all resource files will be in the root folder of your built classes.

Comment: To summarize : using file path without slash makes search in application root folder.

Comment: Thanks guys ! That was useful info !